# Promoting multiple answers using voice recognization

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi

I am working on a game that is based on voice recognization where the user has to recognize the images showing and provide an answer. I have a question in how can I allow the user to provide more than one answer if their first answer was wrong or wasn't recognized for the image shown. I tried using try: and multiple except and I was not able to make it work.

```py
if i== 1:
    carImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path,'tiger.jpg'))
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(130,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:

        print ('Say Something!')
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    except:
        print('Did not get that try Again')
        text=''

    if text == 'tiger':
        print('good job') 
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(right)
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    else:
        print('wrong')
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(wrong)
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    time.sleep(7)
```

```
for i in range(1,3):
       
          
             if i== 1:
         
                   carImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path,'tiger.jpg'))
                   gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(130,0))
                   pygame.display.update()
                   recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
                   microphone = sr.Microphone() 
      
                   for j in range(1,3):
                     text = recognize_speech_from_mic(recognizer, microphone)
                     print(text)
                     if text["transcription"]  == 'tiger':
                       print('good job') 
                       pygame.mixer.Sound.play(right)
                       pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                       break
                       
                       
                     else:
                            print('wrong')
                            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(wrong)
                            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
             time.sleep(4)
             
          
             if i== 2:
        
                     carImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path,'monkey.jpg'))
                     gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(130,0))
                     pygame.display.update()
                     recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
                     microphone = sr.Microphone()
             
                     
                     for u in range(1,3):
                      text = recognize_speech_from_mic(recognizer, microphone)
                      print(text)   
                      if text["transcription"] == 'monkey':
                         print('good job') 
                         pygame.mixer.Sound.play(right)
                         pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                         break
                       
                      
                     else:
                         print('wrong')
                         pygame.mixer.Sound.play(wrong)
                         pygame.mixer.music.stop()
             time.sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using try-except blocks (which is a very ugly pattern for what you are trying to accomplish since it is not an actual error which you are trying to catch but a wrong guess/input by the user), handle the output of `r.recognize_google(audio)` in a more efficient way.

Here is an iterative solution to let the player guess as many times as he wants until he gives a correct answer. It also loops through three example images.

```
def get_audio(r, correct_answers):
   print('Say something!')
   with sr.Microphone() as source:
       audio = r.listen(source)    
       text = r.recognize_google(audio)

   if text in correct_answers:
        print('good job')
        return text
   else:
       print(text + ' was a wrong guess, try again!')
       return get_audio(r)


# Multiple Images are being guessed one after the other
carImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path,'car.jpg'))
tigerImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path,'tiger.jpg'))
lionImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path,'lion.jpg'))
images = []
images.append( (carImg, ['car', 'auto']) )
images.append( (tigerImg, ['tiger', 'lion']) ) 
images.append( (lionImg, ['lion', 'multiple', 'answers']) ) 


for mytuple in images: 
    current_image, correct_answers = mytuple  # unpacking the tuple
    print("Continuing with the next image!")
    gameDisplay.blit(current_image, (130,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    # we need to give get_audio the correct answer now, since it changes with each image:
    correct_guess = get_audio(r, correct_answers)  
    print('You guessed ' + correct_guess + '. This was correct!')
```

Example concerning the breaks from your problem in the comments: We guess the first picture "correct" on the first try, break and continue with the second inner loop.

```
for i in range(1,3):
    print("outer: " + str(i))

    if i == 1:
        print("First picture coming up!")
        for j in range(1,3):
           print("inner_1: " + str(j))
           if 'tiger' == 'tiger':
               print('---> good job!')
               break

    if i == 2:
        print("Second picture coming up!")
        for u in range(1,3):
            print("inner_2: " + str(u))
```

Output:

```
>> outer: 1
>> First picture coming up!
>> inner_1: 1
>> ---> good job!
>> outer: 2
>> Second picture coming up!
>> inner_2: 1
>> inner_2: 2
```

Comment: Thx, for your answer but how can I use the approach you recommend if I have more than one If statement and multiple images.

Comment: @NaifAlhwsawi, I edited the answer - to let the user guess multiple images in a row you need to create a list of images (+ the solution 'word') and then we just loop over this list and let the user guess for each image until he got it right. The above solution might not be perfect, but it should be a good start to continue :)

Comment: Thx.for your help I'll try your method, but I want to check if it's possible to allow the user to provide more than one answer using another for loop. I tried  that but for some reason it's not functioning as I want. It won't break out of the loop and move to the second if statement  when the user say the right answer, it loops twice instead.

Comment: 1. You need to remove your second `break` - it's breaking out of your outer for-loop, you will never reach your `if i == 2` statement.

Comment: 2. Your inner loop just checks `if text["transcription"]  == 'tiger':` multiple times, but the variable does not get changed between the loop iterations. You need to move `recognize_speech_from_mic(recognizer, microphone)`into the inner loop as well (in front of checking the answer).@NaifAlhwsawi

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested, but I am still not able to get to break out of the loop when I say the right answer. I have updated the code. Thx again :)

Comment: out of which loop are you trying to break out of? the inner loops `for j ` or the outer loop `for i` ?  Concerning breaking out of the inner loop - are you sure the correct answer is being recognized?

Comment: I'm trying to break out of the for j loop and move to the If i==2 when the user say the right answer for the first If i==1. And yes I'm sure the correct answer is being recognized because the code is printing out 'good job', but won't break and move to the next if, it'll except second answer even though the first answer was correct

Comment: I added a minimal example with the breaks and it works fine with the same setup. So the problem must be in your code somewhere else.... @NaifAlhwsawi